# Angularjs + RubyonRails + Google Maps Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tProvider <- t

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-directive, angularjs-rails

Iam creating an App with angulajs and rubyon rails.i want to show the google maps to the user for a partiular latituts and longitude i am gettig this kind of error

here is my code.

### Angularjs Directive code

```
app.directive('map', function() {

return {

restrict: "A",

template: "<div id='areaMap'></div>",

    scope: {           
        area: "=",
        zoom: "="
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
        var mapOptions;
        var map;           
        var marker;

        var initialize = function () {                                
            mapOptions = {
                zoom: $scope.zoom,
                //center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, -98.0000),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('areaMap'), mapOptions);
        };

        var createMarker = function (area) {
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(area.Latitude, area.Longitude);
            map.setCenter(position);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: position,
                title: area.Name
            });               
        };

        $scope.$watch("area", function (area) {
            if (area != undefined) {
                createMarker(area);
            }
        });

        initialize();
    },
};
});
```

---

### **Controller**

```
function EventDetailsCtrl($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams, $sce) {  

   var event_id = $routeParams.event_id
   var url = 'API_URL_FOR_JSON';

   $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
     $scope.event = data;
      $scope.Area = { 
                  Name: "Melbourne", 
                  Latitude: data.event.latitude,
                  Longitude: data.event.longitude
                 };
    $scope.latitude = data.event.latitude;
    $scope.longitude = data.event.longitude;
  }); 

}
```

---

### **View file**

```
<div ng-controller ="EventDetailsCtrl">         
   <div map area="Area" zoom="20"></div>
</div>
```

==============================================================

How can i resolve this Issue.pls help
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in creating the controller it should be:

```
app.controller('EventDetailsCtrl',['$scope','$http','$location','$routeParams','$sce',function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams, $sce) {  

   var event_id = $routeParams.event_id
   var url = 'API_URL_FOR_JSON';

   $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
     $scope.event = data;
      $scope.Area = { 
                  Name: "Melbourne", 
                  Latitude: data.event.latitude,
                  Longitude: data.event.longitude
                 };
    $scope.latitude = data.event.latitude;
    $scope.longitude = data.event.longitude;
  }); 

}]);
```

and do remember to boostrap angular using ng-app in html markup (if you have not done that).

It may happen that you minify the js files. If you minify your controller without properly injecting the dependencies it will give a syntax error, so best is to use proper syntax to write a controller having all the dependencies injected as done above.